# Which SQL Server 2008 version to be used

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to install SQL Server 2008 on the server. I wanted to know which edition of SQL Server 2008 would scale for the usage of 350+users. Can you please share your views to select on which would be more appropriate?

1. SQL Server 2008 Datacenter
2. SQL Server 2008 Enterprise (32/64bit)
3. SQL Server 2008 Standard
4. SQL Server 2008 Developer
5. SQL Server 2008 Workgroup

Thanks,

Comment: How much usage by 350 users?  Honestly, there are more criterion than just how many users.

Comment: The Developer edition is **not** licensed to be used in production use

Comment: Better fit for Server Fault? Needs substantially more details though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only user counts to go on and no idea how well the DB is architected AND how well written/designed the software application is for scalability makes this question very hard to say whether you will have scalability problems.  Scalability of SQL Server has been well tested but often it is not SQL Server's fault that something is scaling badly.  It is often a failing of the application code or a poor DB design.

However, with what you have given us information wise.....

Options 1-3 should be fine in general for that many users.

Option 4 is only meant to be on a developers workstation.

Option 5 is meant for small teams / users.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say any of 1, 2 or 3 will work fine.  Which of those you choose is going to depend on what type of application you are developing and what features you will be using.  The Datacenter version is probably overkill, so it's probably going to come down to whether you need the features that Enterprise offers over Standard.

Probably the most significant difference is the CPU support - Standard only supports 4 CPUs.  You can see a detailed comparison [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compare-std-ent.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Generally I think the same as the tow above but it depends also from many various factors.